# how to solve an equation having exponential term

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I have an equation like below

```
y = (x^3-1)((exp(0.019/x))*1.11 -1)
```

[image]

Now for a known value of y how to get x value?

I try to like this

```
from sympy import *
x=Symbol('x')
y=((x**3)-1)*((2.718**(0.019/x))*1.1 -1)
z=solve(y - 0.11,x)
```

Error:

```
NotImplementedError: multiple generators [x, 1359**(1/(1000*x)), 500**(1/(1000*x))]
No algorithms are implemented to solve equation (11*(1359/500)**(19/(1000*x))/10 - 1)*(x**3 - 1) - 11/100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This equation is unlikely to have an analytic solution but can be solved numerically with `nsolve`:

```
In [10]: nsolve(y-.11, x, -1)                                                                                                                  
Out[10]: 1.24743566973735

In [11]: nsolve(y-.11, x, -.1)                                                                                                                 
Out[11]: -0.0897171118541391
```

Comment: what does this -1 and -.1 represent here? @Oscar Benjamin

Comment: Those are initial guesses for the solution.

Comment: Thanks @Oscar Benjamin. I got my answer. But what is the basic difference between solve and nsolve.

Comment: The solve functions tries to find an analytic solution (i.e. express the possible solutions as equations) whereas nsolve finds a numerical solution (estimate the solution to a number of digits)

Answer (score 0):

In python, the `math` module has a method `math.exp`.

Code:

```py
import math

x = 100
y = (x**3-1)*((math.exp(0.019/x))*1.11 -1)
print(y)
```